# Is there more to Azure VM sizes than it would appear?

Tags: azure

I'm trying to choose the best Azure VM for my needs but there's so many varieties it can be very confusing.

For instance I can't see why the `D11` is more expensive than the `D4a`, when the `D11` appears to be a lower spec.

There must be more to it than the basic resources listed here?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The VM sizes which have a lowercase `a` in the name (e.g. D4a v3) are [AMD processors](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/announcing-new-amd-epyc-based-azure-virtual-machines/). Therefore the pricing will be different.

> Finally, we are also announcing new Azure Virtual Machines as part of
>   the Dv3 and Ev3-series—optimized for general purpose and memory
>   intensive workloads. These new VM sizes feature AMD’s EPYC™ 7452
>   processor. The new general purpose Da_v3 and Das_v3 Azure Virtual
>   Machines provide up to 64 vCPUs, 256 GiBs of RAM, and 1,600 GiBs of
>   SSD-based temporary storage. Additionally, the new memory optimized
>   Ea_v3 and Eas_v3 Azure Virtual Machines provide up to 64 vCPUs, 432
>   GiBs of RAM, and 1,600 GiBs of SSD-based temporary storage. Both VM
>   series support Premium SSD disk storage.

Comment: Thanks, mystery solved!  It's ridiculous how Microsoft make the pricing so hard to understand.  I now have to research AMD vs Intel to work out if its right for me, why can't they just rank the sizes by benchmark figures!

Comment: They did, people complained that they wanted the option to pick between Intel and AMD